# Populate react-select field field from firebase

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, react-select

I'm trying to populate the async component of react-select with data from my firebase realtime database.The data doesn't get displayed as the options.

React-Select Docs: https://react-select.com/async

I've tried the callback as well as the promise syntax to populate it.
I'm assuming the react-select field doesn't see the firebase promise as resolved. I don't know how to refactor my code for that.

```
class SelectFilm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.loadOptions = this.loadOptions.bind(this)
    }

    loadOptions = () => {
      database.ref().once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        let films = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((val) => {return {value: val, label: val}})
        console.log(films);
        return films;
      })

    }

    render() {
        return (
              <AsyncSelect
                   cacheOptions
                   defaultOptions 
                   loadOptions={this.loadOptions}                            
              />    
    }

}
```

The returned array films should get read as the options in the react-select field. But the loading indicator of the field doesn't stop. 
I retrieve the data from firebase and also format it the way react-select needs it as I checked by console.log.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a promise from yours `loadOptions` method.

You are missing a `return`:

```
return database.ref().once('value').then(...
```